# How to make custom logger available to all files in Flask Application

Tags: python

I'm new to flask and I was trying to add few more fields to the log in the Python Flask Application. I was using logging module and customized as follows

File name: `logger.py`

```
import logging
from flask import Flask
from flask_log_request_id import current_request_id

APP = Flask(__name__)

class LoggerFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.request_id = current_request_id()
        return True

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addFilter(LoggerFilter())
```

I was trying to use the `logger` in other files as

```
from logger import logger

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def get_list():
    logger.info("Hello")
    # Other codes
```

This is not printing any the logs. My need is to use the custom logger in all places. Please help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just call `getLogger` directly. The `logging` module implements its own namespace of loggers: `getLogger('foo')` returns the same instance of `Logger` no matter where `getLogger` is called.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('logger')

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def get_list():
    logger.info("Hello")
    # Other codes
```

The corollary to this is to *document* the loggers a library expects access to so you can configure them appropriately. (That is, `logging.basicConfig` or similar gets called in your `if __name__ == '__main__'` block, where you do additional configuration. Every library that uses `getLogger` than gets that logger configured by the application.)

Comment: Hi @chepner It is not working. I have a doubt like why are we trying to get logger with name `logger` as we are not setting that name any where.

Comment: The name of the *reference* to the logger should not be important. Access loggers by the name passed to `getLogger`, making sure to use the same name no matter which module is calling `getLogger`. (If you use `getLogger(__name__)` in `logger.py`, you access a logger named `logger`. I you use `getLogger(__name__)` in a different module, you'll be getting a different instance.)